# Array modification [Left Rotation]

Tags: c++, arrays

So, I just solved problem here : [Array Left Rotation - Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-left-rotation)
and after I solved that, i checked other people code
and I'm curious why how his code work, so can you guys help me to find out how his code works.
My code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n;
int d;
cin >> n >> d;
int arr[n];
int lrotate[n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];
}
if (n-d>0)
{
    for (int i=d; i<n;i++)
    {
        lrotate[i-(d)]=arr[i];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        lrotate[i+(n-d)]=arr[i];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << lrotate[i] << " ";
    }
}
}
```

And here's his code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int N, d, i;
cin >> N >> d;
int start = N - d;
int *arr = new int[N];
for (i=0; i<N; ++i)
{
    if (start == N)
        start = 0;
    cin >> arr[start++];
}
for (i=0; i<N; ++i)
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
return 0;
}
```

Sorry if this is a noob question, I am curious how his code works, especially line 7 and line 12.

Comment: The second code doesn't rotate but instead it reads the numbers into the array in the desired order.

Comment: ***I am curious how his code works, especially line 7 and line 12*** This is a perfect time to learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: On SO, when someone posts a question without code, we usually ask "What have you tried so far?". On the other hand, here, what have you understood so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He has used simple algorithm to solve this question.

1. If N==d there is no change in array.
2. If 'start' is not equal to 0, (e.g: start = 3 means, array must be rotate 3 times) in first for loop, the array is filled starting from index 3 to end of the array.
3. Thus start is incrementing gradually, and if start==N, and then start become 0              and again array is filled in index 0 to index 3.

Answer (score 0):

**Left Rotation in JavaScript(Nodejs)**

```
    /*
 * Complete the 'rotLeft' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return an INTEGER_ARRAY.
 * The function accepts following parameters:
 *  1. INTEGER_ARRAY a
 *  2. INTEGER d
 */

    function rotLeft(a, d) {
        // Write your code here
        let tempArr = [];
        let j=0;
        for(let i=d;i<a.length;i++){
            tempArr[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
        for(let i=0;i<d;i++)
        {
            tempArr[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
        return tempArr;
               
    }
```